# How to tune hyper parameters in LSTM, as we increase the classes

Tags: python, keras, classification

I have used the below code for training my model with two labels (binary clssification). Now I have increased the output labels to 5, But it fails with the error

```
embed_size = 128
model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Embedding(max_features, embed_size))
model2.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32, return_sequences = True)))
model2.add(GlobalMaxPool1D())
model2.add(Dense(20, activation="relu"))
model2.add(Dropout(0.05))
//Code changed for Multilevel Classsification
model2.add(Dense(4, activation="softmax"))
model2.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
//Code used for Binary Classifiaction
#model2.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
#model2.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 100
epochs = 3
model2.fit(X_t,y, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.2)
```

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_17 to have
>   shape (4,) but got array with shape (1,)

What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code makes it impossible to debug. Please provide a minimum working example next time (including import libraries, mini dataset etc).

However, if I were to guess correctly, your y is not one hot encoded using `keras.utils.np_utils.to_categorical` so anything other than 1 fails when compilation.

Here's a minimum working example for your case.

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Embedding, LSTM, Bidirectional, GlobalMaxPool1D
from keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

max_features = 20
embed_size = 128
rows = 1000

# Generate some fake data
X_t = np.random.normal(size=(rows,max_features))
y = np.random.binomial(1,0.5,size=rows)

#Convert y to categorical
y_new = to_categorical(y)
y_shape = y_new.shape[1]

model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Embedding(max_features, embed_size))
model2.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32, return_sequences = True)))
model2.add(GlobalMaxPool1D())
model2.add(Dense(20, activation="relu"))
model2.add(Dropout(0.05))
model2.add(Dense(y_shape, activation="softmax")) # note the y_shape here
model2.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
#model2.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
#model2.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 100
epochs = 3
model2.fit(X_t,y_new, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.2)
```